# php security course and other security advice

Tags: php, mysql, security

I have made a web application with PHP and MySQL, and I would like to put it on the web, but I am scared to do so because I am not confident that it is secure. It's not like I'm storing credit card information (It is an app to keep track of income and expenses), however, I still want my users' confidential information to be safe.

I am struggling to find a good course on the topic. I study at [Treehouse](http://teamtreehouse.com) and love it, however, they don't have a course on this topic. I completed [Foundations of Programming: Web Security](http://www.lynda.com/Developer-Web-Development-tutorials/Foundations-Programming-Web-Security/133330-2.html) at Lynda, and while there was a lot of useful information in the course, I still don't really feel confident at making my application secure. It was full of information rather than walking me through the process step by step from start to finish on how to make an application secure.

For example, they recommended Blowfish. But they didn’t walk me through the process of how to actually use it. I didn’t *see* it being used.

So what I don't want: a bunch of links to different sites that have information on security, like the stackoverflow answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4194824/training-courses-or-certification-for-php-security).

What I do want: a video course that starts with a non-secure web-application and shows me the process of making it secure, so that once I’ve completed the course, I know that I can make my web application secure.

At this stage, I am specifically interested in a secure login system, and from Googling, I see that people say it isn’t a good idea to use your own code for that. So I’ve been looking into PHP libraries and frameworks and started learning Laravel, but is this overkill? Should I really need to learn a whole framework just to make my app secure?

So how do web developers gain the confidence to know that their application is secure enough to put on the web, please?

Comment: By today's Stack Overflow standards, the question you point to is off-topic, though it was probably OK when it was asked. I expect yours will, unfortunately, go the same way, though you may get some tips in the comments. We're really looking for specific and answerable questions, whereas this is broad and discursive.

Comment: (I've added a small answer, to get you started).

Comment: There isn't really any one answer to "security". Security is the absence of stupid mistakes. Since there is an infinite number of stupid mistakes you can make in writing your app, there's no infinite answer available covering every possible thing. There are a number of *best practices* to follow for common features like logins, database access and such. The best thing you can do is to read as much about common problems in all areas that may be relevant to you and understand those problems and their mitigations. Rinse, repeat, gain experience.

Comment: @halfer thanks for the reply! Is the following not specific and answerable: What course (online and preferably with video tutorials) can I do that will teach me how to make my web application secure? I'm pretty new to asking questions on stackoverflow. Is it not the place to ask such a question?

Comment: Thank you @deceze for the reply. I know there isn't one answer to security-that's why I was hoping to be pointed to a course that covers the subject.

Comment: And that's something we do not do here. We do not endorse any specific 3rd party content. Troll http://meta.stackoverflow.com if you're interested in the history and specifics of *why*.

Comment: Following on from @deceze, here's a [good number of whys](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=recommendation+questions) and [in particular](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/273050/can-i-ask-the-following-question-on-stack-overflow-or-would-it-become-off-topic/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic things to check:

- Use parameter binding to protect against SQL injection
- Escape output to protect against XSS
- When signing in, regenerate the session ID, to avoid session fixation
- Use best-practice password hashing
- Take care over upload file types (ensure user's cannot upload an executable binary or script, by refusing certain file types or keeping uploaded files out of the docroot)
- Don't inject untainted user input into executed command strings

And if you can afford to:

- Pay a reputable company to do a security audit for you.